# Flutter how to make a selectable / focusable widget

Tags: flutter, focus, android-tv, d-pad

I am creating an android tv app. I was trying to work out for a long time why when I clicked the arrow up and down buttons on the remote it appeared to do nothing and it wasn't selecting any of the list item.

Eventually I was able to work out that if I used an elevated button or other focusable widget on the list i could use the arrow keys and it would work fine. Previously I was using a card widget wrapped in a gesture detector.

So I am wondering what the difference between a button and card with gesture detector is that stops the arrow keys from being able to select the item. I suspect it is the focus.

This is what I was using that doesn't allow the up, down keys on the remote to select it:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Card(
      color: color,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      elevation: 10,
      child: SizedBox(
          width: (width / numberOfCards) - padding * (numberOfCards - 1),
          height: (height / 2) - padding * 2,
          child: Center(child: Text(cardTitle, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),))),
    ),
    onTap: () => onCardTap(),
  ),
```

And this is the button I replaced it with that then makes the up down keys and selection to work:

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Test 1', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3)),
                      minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(60, 60)),
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(10),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50)),)),
                ),
```

In case its needed this is what I am using to pick up the key presses:

```
Shortcuts(
  shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
  },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between your card with gesture detector and the `ElevatedButton` is that you don't have a [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html).

If you dig into the implementation details of the `ElevatedButton` you will find that it uses an [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) with a [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)

```dart
final Widget result = ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: effectiveConstraints,
  child: Material(
    // ...
    child: InkWell(
      // ...
      focusNode: widget.focusNode,
      canRequestFocus: widget.enabled,
      onFocusChange: updateMaterialState(MaterialState.focused),
      autofocus: widget.autofocus,
      // ...
      child: IconTheme.merge(
        // ....
        child: Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: // ...
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

So, if you replace `GestureDetector` with `Inkwell`, then the keyboard navigation would work.

```dart
InkWell(
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    ),
    elevation: 10,
    child: const SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 60,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Test 1',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () {},
)
```

(Tested on Android TV emulator API 30, with keyboard an d-pad.)

#### References

- [Arrow (also D-PAD) keys don't work for focus traversal of TextFormField #49335 | github.com/flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49335)
- [Shift+Tab and arrow (also D-PAD) keys don't work for focus traversal of TextFormField | stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876983/shifttab-and-arrow-also-d-pad-keys-dont-work-for-focus-traversal-of-textform)
- [How to let flutter apps support TV device? | stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844928/how-to-let-flutter-apps-support-tv-device)

Comment: This sounds like GestureDetector should be avoided if one cares about accessibility. Users who require an external switch/keyboard cannot actuate any GestureDetector.